# Python sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing an script which scans a directory recursively and store them in a dictionary which is a collection of list. This list in terns contain list which has file name and size of the file. This file name may contain UTF-8 characters as shown below.

```
['test.rus (\xd0\xa5\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8).srt', 23930]
test.rus (Хельши).srt
```

Now while trying to insert that data into database I am getting error as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filedup.py", line 267, in <module>
    read_file_directory(directory)
  File "filedup.py", line 118, in read_file_directory
    (values[i][0], each, values[i][1]))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

The function which perform this operation is given below

```
from collections import defaultdict
dirDict = defaultdict(list)    
def read_file_directory(path):
    global dirDict
    logger.debug("Path being scanned %s" %path)
    fileStats = []
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file_name in files:
            fileStats = []
            fileStats.insert(0, file_name)
            fileSize = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root,file_name))
            fileStats.insert(1, fileSize)
            dirDict[root].append(fileStats)
    #Insert the data in DB
    cursor = dbHandler.cursor()
    keys = dirDict.keys()
    for each in keys:
        values = dirDict[each]
        print values
        for i in xrange(len(values)):
            print values[i]
            print values[i][0]
            print values[i][1]
            fileName = values[i][0]
            fileSize = values[i][1]
            cursor.execute("insert or ignore into master \
                (FileName, FilePath, FileSize) values(?,?,?)", \
                (values[i][0], each, values[i][1]))
            logger.debug("Insert data for %s, %s, %s" %(values[i][0], each, values[i][1]))
```

Now as I am trying to learn Python I am not getting how to fix this issue. The Python version I am using is given below

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
```

So any thoughts how to fix with current version of Python as I am looking for generic fix so that it can be work even on higher versions.
Also I have observed that due to this error none of the data is being inserted into the database. So how can I make sure that even if some operation result into an error the previous data can be inserted into the database.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using UTF-8 instead of a `unicode`?

Comment: No reason I can use unicode also without any issue.

Comment: Not related to your actual problem, but that `global dirDict` is not good style. It's preferable to pass `dirDict` into the function so that it's signature becomes `def read_file_directory(path, dirDict)`, or, if `dirDict` is not required before `read_file_directory()` is called, create it in `read_file_directory()` and return it from that function.

Comment: @mhawke, Thanks I will update the same. But one quick is references work without any errors as I want to use dirDict at multiple places once it is populated in read_file_directory function. Sorry if this is novice question as I still learning Python.

Comment: @Abhinav in that case just create `dirDict` in `read_file_directory()` and return it. The code that calls the function would then be this: `dirDict = read_file_directory('path/path/path')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sqlite` exception recommends that you switch to unicode strings, so you should do that.

Python's directory listing functions such as `os.walk` has a [curious property](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames); they will return normal strings when given normal strings, and return unicode strings when given unicode strings. Therefore, when using `os.walk(path)` like in your code, you should make sure that `path` is a unicode string.

To do this, you can explicitly convert to unicode using the `unicode()` function, for example by writing `path = unicode(path)` before the call to `os.walk`.

Also, you need to call `cursor.commit()` in your code to actually write to the database. Calling it once after you finished looping through all the filenames should be sufficient.

Comment: How can I make sure that path is a unicode string. Also in the meantime  I am able to move on using below code
`cursor.execute("insert or ignore into master \
                 (FileName, FilePath, FileSize) values(?,?,?)", \
                 (values[i][0].decode('utf-8'), each.decode('utf-8'), values[i][1]))`
But I want to make it unicode so that in future we don't end up in other errors

Comment: @Abhinav it depends. How are you calling this function?

Comment: The function call is   
`read_file_directory(directory)`  
The directory will be passed as part of argument to the script.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the line:

```
fileStats.insert(0, file_name)
```

to

```
fileStats.insert(0, file_name.decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I have done in other way as given below `cursor.execute("insert or ignore into master \ (FileName, FilePath, FileSize) values(?,?,?)", \ (values[i][0].decode('utf-8'), each.decode('utf-8'), values[i][1]))` So that works.

Comment: @Abhinav it might work, but it is probably better to convert to unicode as early as possible, that way you are dealing with unicode internally. @parchment might have a good point about using a unicode path as an argument to `os.walk()` - you should check that out too.

Comment: Ok so I have updated code as `path = unicode(directory)
read_file_directory(path)` and it worked with out using `decode('utf-8')` method. All the values get inserted into database without error.

Comment: @Abhinav : Although the documentation does not explicitly mention `os.walk()`, I've checked out using a unicode path argument to `os.walk` and it works as parchment describes. That's probably the cleanest way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Abhinav - oh, OK then.